# Comparing 2 sets of words in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a query where in i would need to compare 2 sets of words. I need to compare a.error_description with b.KE_TAGS which both contain sets of words.

Example of text: 
**a.error_description** = "LockResource engine call failed in script GLB_LOCK..."
 
**b.KE_TAGS** = "LockResource, GLB_LOCKRESOURCE_100_PS"

Both columns contain the word **"LockResource"**.

Here is my Query below:

The expected result should show the KE_ID based on the KE_TAG "LockResource, GLB_LOCKRESOURCE_100_PS" for the error_description which contains "LockResource engine call failed in script GLB_LOCK..."

```
Select a.error_id, a.job_ID, a.error, a.error_description, 
            CONCAT('%',b.KE_TAGS,'%'), b.KE_TAGS, b.KE_ID
from errors_input as a right join knowledge_entry as b
 on a.error_Description like CONCAT('%',b.KE_TAGS,'%') -- issue is in this line
 WHERE a.error like '%BB_RAISEERROR_100_PS%'***
```

Hope you can help. thanks!

Comment: Your bKE_TAGS id a couple of word but seems you need/can  compare (like) only the word LockResource .. is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: You have a problem with unnormalized data, you should not have a set of things in one column. If your tag is one thing (e.g. `LockResource` is the name, `GLB_LOCKRESOURCE_100_PS` is the code for it), split them into two columns (then you can use your query). If these are two different things, add them as two rows. Having unnormalized data usually makes problems more complicated than they actually are (as you can see e.g. here).

Comment: @scaisEdge Yes correct,but only for this situation. There will be cases where the error_description will contain both 'LockResource' and 'GLB_LOCKRESOURCE_100_PS' or just 'GLB_LOCKRESOURCE_100_PS'. Basically, i am trying to compare two sentences with each other matching them when both contain the same words but not all of it.

Comment: @Solarflare Unfortunately the KE(knowledge entry) is already too long to keep which is why i made KE_TAGS column which contains a set of keywords from the whole knowledge entry.Some tags have more keywords  so splitting them into different columns might not be possible.

Comment: @raymond.marzan  if  the situation is like you described in your comment  .. you have i big problem  because is not esay in SQL tokenize eache word and perform the like for each word .. because a partial pattern match is not possibile with like .. probabily you must toleknize the tags server side ..

Comment: As I wrote, if you have more words, put them in rows. That is how sets work in sql. If you don't think it is possible, post some examples, I ensure you it is. There is one other possiblity, that you actually shouldn't use, because your database design is broken (unnormalized) right now, and it's better to fix it (and you probably won't do it if you have a workaround), but since it's not my job to force you to do it: if your data is exactly as described, you can use a fulltext index for description, and then use `where match(a.error_Description) against(b.KE_TAGS in BOOLEAN MODE)`